# didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge not getting called

Tags: ios5

I am using iOS sdk5.0. I am hitting a link using NSURLConnection and creating a request. But my control is not going into didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge method. Is didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge not called in iOS5.0?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLConnectionDelegate) of `NSURLConnectionDelegate`

```
connection:canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:
connection:didReciveAuthenticationChallenge:
connection:didCancelAuthenticationChallenge:
```

are deprecated and new code should adopt

```
connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge
```

The older delegates will still be called for compatibility, but incur more latency in dealing with the authentication challenge.

Comment: thanks himanshu. So, instead of this methods if NSURLConnectionDelegate, i should use connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge (in iOS 5). But when i will run this code in a version other than 5.0, then it would give error. Right??

Comment: again according to [Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLConnectionDelegate) `If connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge: is not implemented, the older, deprecated methods connection:canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:, connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:, and connection:didCancelAuthenticationChallenge: are called instead.`

Comment: I've got an implementation of the new one, willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge that I set up as the delegate, and it's not getting called.  I'm trying to get around using a self-signed cert for testing, and I get API request failed with error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.", etc. Searches indicate this delegate method should allow me to do this, but the delegate isn't even getting called.

Comment: @ChrisWestin did you ever solve your issues with error -1200?  I am working through the same issue.

Comment: @GregMartin: yes, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem (see my comment above). In my searches, I came across this gist: https://gist.github.com/1675763 . I tried the code in the AUTH_NEW path. The delegate still wasn't being called. Then I noticed the comment on line 40:
"Perhaps iOS 5 can't support DSA signature algorism."

I did some searches, and found nothing to indicate that this was a limitation was a problem. Finally, in desperation, I changed this. I was using java's keytool (Java's reinvented version of openssl+) to generate my self-signed cert. It uses DSA by default. Out of desperation, I used a flag to force it to use RSA. Then the delegate got called, and the code in the gist above worked.

I still have yet to see any documentation that says you can't use DSA. openssl seems to use RSA by default, so folks using that probably never run into this.

Short story: check your cert and make sure it is signed with RSA and not DSA.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to emphasize the point Chris Westin makes. And beyond that, I actually created an RSA key, but accidentally copied the DSA one to the server. So when in doubt, you need to use the -v (verbose) command to make sure that you've got the proper cert in place. Example:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore <name of keystore here>
```